# Implementing efficient foreign keys in a relational database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql

All popular SQL databases, that I am aware of, implement foreign keys efficiently by indexing them.

Assuming a N:1 relationship Student -> School, the school id is stored in the student table with a (sometimes optional) index. For a given student you can find their school just looking up the school id in the row, and for a given school you can find its students by looking up the school id in the index over the foreign key in Students. Relational databases 101.

But is that the only sensible implementation? Imagine you are the database implementer, and instead of using a btree index on the foreign key column, you add an (invisible to the user) set on the row at the other (many) end of the relation. So instead of indexing the school id column in students, you had an invisible column that was a set of student ids on the school row itself. Then fetching the students for a given school is a simple as iterating the set. Is there a reason this implementation is uncommon? Are there some queries that can't be supported efficiently this way? The two approaches seem more or less equivalent, modulo particular implementation details. It seems to me you could emulate either solution with the other.

In my opinion it's conceptually the same as splitting of the btree, which contains sorted runs of (school_id, student_row_id), and storing each run on the school row itself. Looking up a school id in the school primary key gives you the run of student ids, the same as looking up a school id in the foreign key index would have.

**edited for clarity**

Comment: The reason it is uncommon is that it violates the rule of atomicity and leads to lots of query-writing problems down the road.

Comment: Your question is too vague to offer much of a discussion. What do you mean a column being a set? Are you saying store a delimited list in a single column? This is a violation of 1NF. Maybe that isn't your question though.

Comment: A column with all students would require either a comma delimited column or perhaps an XML document or something weird like that. Neither good options and violations Normalization rules. The only way to sensibly separate the foreign key from the students table would be an association table, but this is normally reserved for N:N relationships. for N:1 it just isn't necessary and an FK with an index in Students is genuinely the most sensible strategy.

Comment: Short answer is, not surprisingly - yes. That is the only sensible implementation.

Comment: N.B. That may well be, but it's not clear to me that it's the best implementation.

Comment: And consider the possible data integrity problems it could create and the problem of updating the records and how large the iterated list would get.  And then tehre is extensibility - what if you need to add data surrounding each value later on? SO right now you list the part numbers ina comma delimited list, waht happens when you need to start storing details about the part numbers?

Comment: @HLGEM those are all implementation details. You could use a list for small numbers of values and switch to a btree or hashset for larger numbers, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might buy you some small benefit in a narrow set of cases. But the drawbacks are numerous.

1. Such indices are useful for more than just direct joins from the parent record. A query might `GROUP BY` the FK column, or join it to a temp table / subquery / CTE; all of these cases might benefit from the presence of an index, but none of the queries involve the parent table.
2. Even direct joins from the parent often involve additional constraints on the child table. Consequently, indices defined on child tables commonly include other fields in addition to the key itself.
3. Even if there appear to be fewer steps involved in this algorithm, that does not necessarily equate to better performance. Databases don't read from disk a column at a time; they typically load data in fixed-size blocks. As a result, storing this information in a contiguous structure may allow it to be accessed far more efficiently than scattering it across multiple tuples.
4. No database that I'm aware of can inline an arbitrarily large column; either you'd have a hard limit of a few thousand children, or you'd have to push this list to some out-of-line storage (and with this extra level of indirection, you've probably lost any benefit over an index lookup).
5. Databases are not designed for partial reads or in-place edits of a column value. You would need to fetch the entire list whenever it's accessed, and more importantly, replace the entire list whenever it's modified.
6. In fact, you'd need to duplicate the entire *row* whenever the child list changes; the [MVCC model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) handles concurrent modifications by maintaining multiple versions of a record. And not only are you spawning more versions of the record, but each version holds its own copy of the child list.
7. Probably most damning is the fact that an insert on the child table now triggers an update of the parent. This involves locking the parent record, meaning that concurrent child inserts or deletes are no longer allowed.

I could go on. There might be mitigating factors or obvious solutions in many of these cases (not to mention outright misconceptions on my part), though there are probably just as many issues that I've overlooked. In any case, I'm satisfied that they've thought this through fairly well...

Comment: Thanks for thinking this through, this is exactly the kind of response I'm looking for. For some context I'm working on an in-memory relational database. I'm implementing the foreign key strategy discussed in this post and trying to see if I've overlooked some major drawback. I'll respond to your points.

Comment: 1) Group by is easier, just iterate the parent table, in primary key order, iterating each set of foreign keys. It's already grouped. Not sure if there's a kind of join or query that one might use that couldn't be supported efficiently though.

Comment: 4) It does have an extra indirection, but a btree index is an indirection for every level of the tree. So it wins here.

Comment: 2) Yes you're right. I don't see an easy way around composite indices here. One could filter the child table first by the secondary criteria, and then hash join that with the foreign key sets from the parent, but it's sub-optimal.

Comment: 3) doesn't apply to an in-memory database (there is cache locality, but this scheme should have better cache locality for most queries.) 5) and 6) are really the same thing and not a limitation of my implementation. 7) is also not a limitation as all writes are single-threaded and there are no locks in my database (MVCC with a single-writer doesn't seem to need locks.)

Comment: @Eloff: With no disk and no concurrency to worry about, it might be feasible. Certainly worth a try if you're building your own database. To follow up on a couple of points:

Comment: 1) An index solves the more general problem of mapping a key value to a child record's location. In this general case, you'll still need to go through the parent's PK index to locate the set. The optimisation only targets the cases where you're interested in *all* key values, or where you've already located the parent row through other means. The other issue here is that you'd be dragging the parent table into queries which don't otherwise involve it, which might limit concurrency at higher isolation levels.

Comment: 4) Unless you're limited to fixed-width rows, you'll still need an extra step to locate the child set within the parent tuple, so I think you'd break even. If you're not fetching the rest of the columns, I'd expect cache locality to put the B-tree slightly in front.

Comment: 2) This is commonly done by basically building a per-row bitmap for each condition, then ANDing them all together. [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html) and [Firebird](https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/general/doc_68) all support this; check their source code for details.

Comment: All good points, I appreciate your insights. You seem to be very knowledgeable about databases. So in this case the rows are fixed-width and lookup by row id is not a btree lookup (which would make this scheme pointless!) but a simple address calculation. I am aware of the per-row bitmap strategy, but it seems very specialized to me. If you have even one index that's very selective you're better off just using that index alone and checking the other conditions against the indexed rows one at a time. The bitmap is best when you have many indexed columns in your criteria and none are selective.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be suggesting storing "comma separated list of values" as a string in a character column of a table. And you say that it's "as simple as iterating the set".

But in a relational database, it turns out that "iterating the set" when its stored as list of values in a column is not at all simple. Nor is it efficient. Nor does it conform to the relational model.

Consider the operations required when a member needs to be added to a set, or removed from the set, or even just determining whether a member is in a set. Consider the operations that would be required to enforce integrity, to verify that every member in that "comma separated list" is valid. The relational database engine is not going to help us out with that, we'll have to code all of that ourselves.

At first blush, this idea may seem like a good approach. And it's entirely possible to do, and to get some code working. But once we move beyond the trivial demonstration, into the realm of real problems and real world data volumes, it turns out to be a really, really bad idea.

The storing comma separated lists is all-too-familiar SQL anti-pattern.

I strongly recommend Chapter 2 of Bill Karwin's excellent book: [SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)  ISBN-13: 978-1934356555

---

(The discussion here relates to "relational database" and how it is designed to operate, following the relational model, the theory developed by Ted Codd and Chris Date.)

**"All nonkey columns are dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key. So help me Codd."**

---

**Q: Is there a reason this implementation is uncommon?**

Yes, it's uncommon because it flies in the face of relational theory. And it makes what would be a straightforward problem (for the relational model) into a confusing jumble that the relational database can't help us with. If what we're storing is just a string of characters, and the database never needs to do anything with that, other than store the string and retrieve the string, we'd be good. But we can't ask the database to decipher that as representing relationships between entities.

**Q: Are there some queries that can't be supported efficiently this way?**

Any query that would need to turn that "list of values" into a set of rows to be returned would be inefficient. Any query that would need to identify a "list of values" containing a particular value would be inefficient. And operations to  insert or remove a value from the "list of values" would be inefficient.

Comment: This is the answer I expected, but I'm going to push back here. To answer this question you need to provide a concrete counter-example of a tangible shortcoming of the "inline set" approach. Let me clarify that it's not the database user defining some comma-delimited set. This is the database implementation transparently replacing a foreign key index with an invisible set on each foreign row. I maintain it's functionally equivalent, and may even be a superior implementation because there's no btree lookup involved to "join" the foreign key, you just iterate the set.

Comment: @Eloff, If you thinkyou idea is so great (frnakly it horrifies me), then fill in a database this way and make sure to 10,000,000 rows each with it's commadelimieed set and then try to query it.  Make sure to try to get individual values of that set. Relational databases are optimized to handle foerign keys,. They are not optiomized for this stuff. If youw ant to do iot, then yuo also need to consider if it may be that you need a nosql database instead of a relational one. Or  maybe just hire a database developer before you go off on the deep end .

Comment: @HLGEM you misunderstand me, I'm not considering using this in an existing database, I'm asking what if databases used this implementation under the hood. You, the user, would be none the wiser.

Comment: @Eloff, what we are saying is iti s going to affect performance, badly.  If you think youi are smarter than the people who designed relational databases, go ahead and try it on your own in large system, but don't bet your professional work on this. You would be doing your company a disservice to commit to such an approach without proving first that it can handle large amounts of data and large reporting queries outide of a copmany project.  I would suggest you read books on performance tuning, SQL antipartterns, and database internals before you go down this road.

Comment: @HLGEM: As he said, he's not suggesting that any user implement this in their own database. He's just pondering whether the RDBMS itself could structure its index information this way, as opposed to a using B-tree.

Comment: @Eloff: I misunderstood your question. I thought you were asking about "implementing" an entity-relationship model in some "popular SQL database". I didn't recognize that your question was postulating an invisible feature of a storage engine used by an RDBMS. I suppose it's possible. But the description of the feature doesn't seem to conform to the fundamental tenets of the relational model. (I think we're more likely to find such a mechanism in non-relational databases.)